Sum of Taylor series with rising factorial
I have the following series: $$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{a^{(n)}}{n!}x^n$$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a parameter and $a^{(n)}$ is the rising factorial.
How can I find its sum elegantly? I can't even find if it converges - $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n}$ gives 1, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ is a root of factorials which I can't seem to evaluate, integrating is off since the factorial function is discrete. Sterling's approximation is not useful as it can't cancel out with the rising factorial and I'd rather not use the gamma function as it'll change the original sum (when replacing $n!$). Wolfram Alpha gives an ugly result including hypergeometric functions and doesn't give an insight as to how it got to it. How do I evaluate this sum?

Hint.  Investigate the binomial coefficient $$\binom{-a}{n}$$

Try the nth derivative of   $(1+x) ^a$ at $x=0$

Note simply that you can re-express as
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(a+k)}{\Gamma(a)}~\frac{x^k}{k!}\equiv {}_1F_0(a;\mid x)$$
From here there are to ways to solve the problem. The first is to simply look up
$${}_1F_0(a;\mid x)=(1-x)^{-a}$$
The other way is to write out the corresponding differential equation:
$$x\left(x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}+a\right)w(x)=x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}w(x) \\ \implies x^2w'(x)+ax~w(x)=x~w'(x) \\ x~w'(x)+a~w(x)=w'(x) \\ w'(x)=\frac{a}{1-x}w(x)$$
Which can be easily solved as $w(x)=c_1(1-x)^{-a}$.
EDIT: In regards to convergence, the sum only converges for $|x|<1$, however, it may be analytically continued to $\mathbb C\setminus \{1\}$ in the standard way.
